# Giving index.html priority over index.php

Tags: wordpress, indexing

I have a wordpress site. Now the index page is index.php

Problem is that I don't want the server to use the **index.php** as the default one, but instead the **index.html**.

the **index.html** is just a temp page (under construction) until the wordpress site is ready.

currently the domain gives precedence to **index.php** - How do i give it to index.html?

NOTE: I do **not** have an htaccess file in the root....
I believe you specify it in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your server configuration for now, some .htaccess file you may not have access too. You can define/overrule this in your own htaccess using, for example :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

the priority depends on the order you set the filenames in that line

Answer (score 2):

make an .htaccess file with "DirectoryIndex index.html"  (no qoutes) in it.